# Im getting NULL Values in my query

Tags: null

Im getting NULL values in my query:

```html
SELECT substring(hex(ent_id), 1, 3) AS fleetId, substring(hex(ent_id), 4, 16) AS taxiId, 
(ent_requested_time)'Partio el dia',
SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(ent_requested_time + ent_dropoff_time))as totales,
SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(ent_requested_time + ent_pickup_time - ent_dropoff_time)) as 'totales sin pasajero',
SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(ent_pickup_time + ent_dropoff_time - ent_requested_time)) as 'totales con pasajero'
FROM tf_entities
WHERE '2015-03-01' <= ent_requested_time and ent_requested_time < '2015-04-01' 
order by taxiId ASC
```

This is what SQL shows me:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zprNi.jpg)

What can I do in this situation? How can i change or modify my query in order to not get that values NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is this part for:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(ent_requested_time + ent_dropoff_time))as totales,
```

But if you want to remove null values you can add some conditions in your WHERE clauses
Try add this in there:

```
AND !ISNULL(ent_requested_time) AND !ISNULL(ent_dropoff_time)
```

Comment: Hey! 
Im still getting those NULL values, I added you Clauses but nothing happened.

Comment: could you add the table structure and some sample data?